# 7Random ASCII chars in footer?

Tags: 7

[image: drupal random ascii chars in footer]

goes away when I clear the cache but comes back as soon as I visit another page.

- new standard installation (drupal 7.32)
- lighttpd + php 5.4 (fpm)
- mariadb

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a `collation` issue in your database tables. Perhaps you copy and pasted some text from a Word file or other file that had a weird character set encoding and when it was saved to the database the proper text was lost in the transition.

I recommend looking at where the text in your footer is coming from originally, a foreign webpage, an MS Word file, an XML file -- and what encoding it has.

Then I would recommend you look at the [Collation Fixer](https://www.drupal.org/project/collation_fixer) module which is designed to *help* with this issue. It will properly set your set tables to 1 Collation -- you must then provide the correct text/prose/verbiage into your footer so that its in the same character set the database expects.

> A 'runtime' requirements checker (admin/reports/status) for checking
>   all database tables have the right database collation (probably very
>   MySQL centric).
>
> Offers the ability to fix tables with wrong database collation.
>
> The collation is either specified in your database settings or in
>   hook_schema() or hook_schema_alter().
>
> This can be useful when developing non-english sites.
>
> Example of specifying in database settings in settings.php (will
>   affect all tables - it's probably better to do it in hook_schema() or
>   hook_schema_alter()):

```
<?php
$databases = array(
  'default' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'database' => 'my-db',
      'username' => 'my-user',
      'password' => 'my-password',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
      'collation' => 'utf8_danish_ci',
    ),
  ),
);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! The collation on all tables are the default (e.g. utf8_general_ci). The content is not in the sourcecode (at least I can't find it). Also "collation" in mysql has nothing to do with how the data is being saved but has to do with sorting.